# Using Generics to return a literal string or from Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, generics

I think I outsmarted myself this time.  Feel free to edit the title also I could not think of a good one.

I am reading from a file and then in that file will be a string because its like an xml file. But in the file will be a literal value or a "command" to get the value from the workContainer

so

```
<Email>me@company.com</Email>
```

or

```
<Email>[? MyEmail ?]</Email>
```

What I wanted to do instead of writing ifs all over the place to put it in a generic function

so logic is

```
If Container command grab from container else grab string and convert to desired type 
Its up to the user to ensure the file is ok and the type is correct
```

so another example is

so

```
<Answer>3</Answer>
```

or

```
<Answer>[? NumberOfSales ?]</Answer>
```

This is the procedure I started to work on

```
public class WorkContainer:Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public T GetKeyValue<T>(string Parameter) 
    {
        if (Parameter.StartsWith("[? "))
        {
            string key = Parameter.Replace("[? ", "").Replace(" ?]", "");

            if (this.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return (T)this[key];
            }
            else
            {
                // may throw error for value types
                return default(T);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            // Does not Compile
            if (typeof(T) is string)
            {
                return Parameter
            }
            // OR return (T)Parameter

        }
    }
}
```

The Call would be

```
  mail.To = container.GetKeyValue<string>("me@company.com");
```

or

```
  mail.To = container.GetKeyValue<string>("[? MyEmail ?]");

  int answer = container.GetKeyValue<int>("3");
```

or

```
  answer = container.GetKeyValue<int>("[? NumberOfSales ?]");
```

But it does not compile?

Comment: What compile error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer I came up with, I am a little worried about boxing and unboxing but it works for now

```
public class WorkContainer:Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public T GetKeyValue<T>(string Parameter) 
    {
        if (Parameter.StartsWith("[? "))
        {
            string key = Parameter.Replace("[? ", "").Replace(" ?]", "");

            if (this.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(string) )
                {
                    // Special Case for String, especially if the object is a class
                    // Take the ToString Method not implicit conversion
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(this[key].ToString(), typeof(T));
                }
                else
                {
                    return (T)this[key];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return default(T);
            }

        }
        else
        {                
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Parameter, typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(string))
{
    return (T)Parameter;
}
else
{
    // convert the value to the appropriate type
}
```

Comment: Still Errors Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'T'

Comment: @Mike: My mistake; even with the logic there, a cast is still necessary. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (typeof(T) is string)
```

will always return false sine the typeof operator gives a Type object. You should replace it with

```
if (T is string)
```

In addition you should look at the [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) method. It may be of help here.

Comment: Err...no. Your solution will not compile. The `is` operator is used to determine if a *value* (either variable, literal, or constant) is of a particular *type*. It cannot be used to compare two *types*.

Comment: I gave you +1 because even though your T is string wrong Convert.ChangeType was the key.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof(T) == typeof(string)`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (typeof(T) is string)
```

to:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
```

The is operator is only valid on class instances.  T is not actually an instance it is a type, therefor using is will not compile in your code because you need to compare 2 types. You can read more about it on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Even though if (typeof(T) == typeof(String)) works the return was still an issue 

Still Errors Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'T'