# Returning a generic type with a base class constraint from a function without casting in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing a game in Unity that has a bunch of different kinds of items that can go in the players inventory. There is a base class ItemSettings that has properties that all items contain, and then one level of derived types for guns, components, armor, etc. All items are identified uniquely by an enum value, and I have a class that manages dictionaries of that enum => the item's setting.

The basic class hierarchy:

```
class ItemSettings {
  public Item itemIdenfitier;
  public ItemCategory itemCategory;
}

class GunSettings : ItemSettings {...}

class ComponentSettings: ItemSettings {...}
```

Here is the singleton class that maintains dictionaries for all ItemSettings types, and a function that lets callers retrieve a specific item setting:

```
    public static TItemType Get<TItemType>(Item item) where TItemType : ItemSettings
    {
        ItemSettings itemSetting;
        switch (Instance.itemCategoryMap[item])
        {
            case ItemCategory.Gun:
                itemSetting = Instance.gunMap[item];
                break;
            case ItemCategory.Component:
                itemSetting = Instance.componentMap[item];
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Item category not found for item {item}");
        }

        return (TItemType) itemSetting;
    }
```

I don't understand why I have to do the casting in this way, instead of just returning the dictionary values themselves like this:

```
    public static TItemType Get<TItemType>(Item item) where TItemType : ItemSettings
    {
        switch (Instance.itemCategoryMap[item])
        {
            case ItemCategory.Gun:
                return Instance.gunMap[item];
            case ItemCategory.Component:
                return Instance.componentMap[item];
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Item category not found for item {item}");
        }
    }
```

I get the error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type GunSettings to TItemType`

However, TItemType has the constraint that it must be an ItemSettings, which should apply to GunSettings. I must be missing some nuance of the C# generics system.

Comment: You can refer to this thread [C# Generic Method, cannot implicit convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057620/c-sharp-generic-method-cannot-implicit-convert) basically, `TItemType` isn't known at compile time

Comment: `TItemType` is an `ItemSettings`, but the reverse is not necessarily true. All the compiler knows is that `itemSetting` is an `ItemSettings`, and not that it happens to have the desired return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling code would look something like:

```
GunSettings setting = Get<GunSettings>(item);
```

But what if item was a Component and not a Gun?  Then it couldn't be cast to GunSetting.  The explicit cast is required because while *you* may know that the function will always fetch an ItemSettings instance of the correct subtype, the compiler does not.